# How to create an EC2 instance from .tar.gz?

Tags: linux, file-transfer, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vps

Suppose I have a `.tar.gz` file with a Linux filesystem.

How to create an AWS EC2 Compute Instance from this file?

Actually, I want to move a server from Lightsail to EC2. Maybe, instead use rsync or something? How?

Answer (score 0):

See the article AWS Support article
[How can I migrate a Windows Lightsail instance to an Amazon EC2 instance for troubleshooting purposes?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lightsail-migrate-to-ec2/)

As the contents of the article might change in the future, here is
just a rough summary of the steps:

- Create a Lightsail snapshot and export it
- Create a new EC2 instance from the exported snapshot
- Troubleshoot or recover data from the Lightsail snapshot.

Note: To export a Windows Lightsail instance to Amazon EC2 for
reasons other than troubleshooting, see the article
[Creating a snapshot of your Windows Server instance in Amazon Lightsail](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/prepare-windows-based-instance-and-create-snapshot).
This advises to run Sysprep to create a snapshot with
system-specific information removed from your instance.

Comment: this about Windows, the question is about Linux. While the general steps are near identical, sysprep is a windows specfific thing

Comment: @SathyajithBhat: You're right - answer modified.